# CefPython3, PySide, and cx_freeze: Can't get EXE working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, cx-freeze, chromium-embedded

I recently downloaded an installed the following:

1. **Python 3.2.5**
2. **CefPython 3**
3. **PySide** - for handling the GUI of my CEF-powered app
4. **cx_freeze** - to make my app distributable

Now, the first three work just fine. If I run `pyside.py` in CefPython's examples directory, the app starts as it should. However, if I try to freeze the app using the instruction below, the app compiles, but with errors.

**Command line instruction**

```
C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\examples\PySide>cxfreeze pyside.py --target-dir bin --base-name Win32GUI --include-modules atexit,PySide.QtNetwork
```

**Error**

```
Missing modules:
? _gestalt imported from platform
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? cefpython_py27 imported from __main__
? cefpython_py32 imported from __main__
? win32api imported from platform
? win32con imported from platform
? win32pipe imported from platform
```

Then, when I try to run the app, I get the following:

```
ImportError: No module named cefpython_py32
```

Problem here is that I can't seem to include the module in the command line instruction. cx_freeze simply cannot find it.

What do I need to do to get cx_freeze to find CefPython?

**Note:** cx_freeze imports all the necessary DLLs, from the Qt framework, to CefPython itself. They are all there. Which begs the question as to why it knows where the DLLs are, but not the libraries. Also note that I'm a Python newbie. I'm sure there's a simple explanation as to what I need to do. I have a feeling I need to copy something into cx_freeze's `dist` directory - I just don't know what that file would be. I naturally assumed it would be a `.pyc` file, but there are none...

#### Update (whilst I was compiling this question):

I also tried the following instruction:

```
C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\examples\PySide>cxfreeze pyside.py --target-dir bin --base-name Win32GUI --include-modules atexit,PySide.QtNetwork,cefpython3
```

Note the added `cefpython3`. Now, it compiles it, but the EXE throws a cx_freeze error: `Cannot get zipimporter instance` Also, the above errors persist, and so I think that using `cefpython3` is wrong in this regard.

Comment: Is there a `cefpython_32.pyd` file you can try copying into your bin directory?

Comment: Yeah, but no bin directory...

Comment: When you say `--target-dir bin`, does that not make a bin directory? If not, put it in whatever directory cx_Freeze is copying your app.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. I did change the directory, so I got confused there. But now, does that file have to be shipped with the app? Is there no way to embedd it?

Comment: All the files in that folder have to be shipped together; cx_Freeze doesn't have a single-file mode. There are ways to make an installer for it.

Comment: Though that may not answer your question, I tried cx_Freeze and PyInstaller and all that stuff for my python application, which also uses pyside. And after a couple of days of no progress getting the application to work, I now use an InnoSetup script instead, which is more portable across languages and thus offers a better investment of your time. From my knowledge, cx_Freeze is not tested to work with PySide.